# Replace substring containing '+'

Tags: jquery, replace

I have a string with sub-string '5+' and it looks like `sales/100/5+`. I need to remove the sub-string `5+`.

Input  : `sales/100/5+`

Demanded output : `sales/100`

The jquery script is as follows:

```
var rstring = 'sales/100/5+';
if((splitStr == '5+')||(splitStr == '4-')) {
    var key = rstring.replace(new RegExp('/'+splitStr, 'g'),"");
    alert(key);
}
```

Now im getting the result  : sales/100+

But desired output is      : sales/100

Comment: Is the part to be replace always "5+" / "4-"  or is it gonna be the part after last "/" ??

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you can `split()` the string by `/`, remove the last element, then `join()` it back together, like this:

```js
var arr = 'sales/100/5+'.split('/');
arr.pop();

console.log(arr.join('/'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to use a Regex to make your string replace work

the simplest the best :

```
  var rstring = 'sales/100/5+';
  if((splitStr == '5+')||(splitStr == '4-')) 
  {
       var key = rstring.replace('/' + splitStr, '');
       alert(key);
  }
```

the '+' in your Regex is a quantifier. It matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed.
That's why your + was still ther after your replace.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `/5+` from given strings. No jQuery code is neede, just a simple JS function.

```
function replace5plus(str) {
    return str.replace('/5+', '');
}
```